# How to correctly and consistently mock location in Android?

Tags: java, android, gps

Here's what I tried:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    locationManager.addTestProvider(provider, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, 0, Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(provider, true);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Location location = new Location(provider);
            location.setLatitude(...);
            location.setLongitude(...);
            location.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
            locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(provider, location);

            handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, INTERVAL);
```

The problem is, no matter how low I set the INTERVAL, the marker on Google Map can't seem to stay at the mocked location. It always flashes back to original location until `run()` on `Runnable` is called again. I believe there is a legitimate way of mocking location than my looping Handler.

Comment: Wanna see mocked location on Google Maps app ?

Comment: @Blackkara no, not exclusively for Google Map. I am just using marker on Google Map to test if I have correctly set mocked location.

Comment: The reason of asking it : If you wanna see you mock location on Google Maps app itself, then you need to mock fused location provider. Anyway, your code is right, but be sure which provider you requesting for updates. It means, if name of test provider is "XYX provider", then you need call **requestLocationUpdates("XYX provider", ...);**

Comment: @Blackkara are you implying that I need to call requestLocationUpdates()? What logic or operation should be in the LocationListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this line

```
locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(provider, location);
```

It sets current location of this provider, let's assume my test provider is AbcProvider

```
String provider = "AbcProvider";
location.setProvider(provider);
locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(provider, location);
```

- locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("AbcProvider"); returns currently set location
- onLocationChanged() will be fired **if you called** requestLocationUpdates("AbcProvider", ...);

Your code has no problem ! But be clear on where you wanna see result of mocking. After running your code, if you looking **Google Maps app** itself, mocking will not be working because it's not getting location through the LocationManager.